# MATLAB - color encode plot

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I specify something like: if the plotted value is < 10, color it red, if it is >20 color it blue, if it is in between color it black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example:

```
x=1:0.1:30;
y=x;

hold on
plot(x(y<10), y(y<10),'o','color','red');
plot(x(y>20),y(y>20),'o','color','blue');
```

the y(y<10) is [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/), and is the key to this.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work if you're plotting surfaces.

```
set(gca, 'CLim', [0 30])
set(gcf, 'Colormap', [1 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are plotting a line then I'd recommend using [color_line](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19476-colored-line-or-scatter-plot) from MATLAB Central. You will still need to set the colour map you require but using this method you are plotting one line coloured according to a value.

The one drawback with using the logical indexing to seperate the data is that when you plot it they are treated as seperate blocks of data. So many of the plot tools will only work on one set of data, put up a legend and you will get one item for each set of data.

With color_line it will be different colours but it will be treated as one data item.